# How do I save flask login session in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flask

So I have a flutter app. And also I have a backend api with flask. The way the api works is, if you log into the api, the api will let you use a database and you can create data there. We can easily do this in browser. In browser or Postman, it automatically saves the login session. But in flutter they don't save the login session automatically. What is the best way to save login session just like a browser in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `jsonDecode(response.body)` and then store the information therein in SharedPreferences (package that abstracts access to local device storage). If you have need for the cookie, you can find it in the `jsonDecode(response.headers)`. Store this information in an object then save to sharedpreferences. Once that is done, set up your app to always fetch the info first at start up so that it can be used in the application through whatever state management you use

To POST the data, install and use this package called **http**. There are instructions on how to use it but here is a short snippet.

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future postExample() async{
  final url = Uri.parse('https://your-url.com');
  final response = await http.post(url, headers{}, body{});//add required data in headers and body although for logging in the header would typically be empty
  log(response.body); //This is just to see the output in the terminal

}
```

Comment: How do I post data and let the api know that I'm logged in?

Comment: I actually don't know a lot about web stuff like login logout get post. Do you use header to let the api know that you are logged in? Is header basically like cookies?

Comment: I have edited my answer with more info. The header does typically carry auth tokens and or cookies so that the server knows the client has a valid session. To log in/out, you would send data through the body of the post, typically login credentials,

Comment: thank you. I'll try using this method, first save the header info and then use the post method to pass that header info, so that the server knows that I have a valid session, all right?

Comment: First you POST the login info (username, pass). The server will respond with info like token, timestamps etc in the response. body. In the response.header, you can find the cookie if it's not in the body